# Mobile view of Community Site Template

Tags: 2013, mobile, community-site

Is there any way to enable mobile views and / or device channels on the Community Site Template, without custom development?

I've tried enabling the site publishing feature, but even then there is no option for me to edit or modify the mobile view.